# Accessing the two 'this' variables in Function.prototype

Tags: javascript, function, this, prototype-programming

I'd like to extend Function.prototype with a custom method:

```
Function.prototype.myMethod = function() {
     var fn = this;
     var owner = ???;
     /** ... */
};
```

`this` in that scope refers to the original function. But how do I access the `this` that refers to the object that "owns" the function (or whatever the outer `this` is at the time that `fn` is called)?

Comment: I think you can't know it because you are actually not calling the "original" function. There is no way to know whether the function is assigned to a property or not. What are you trying to do? Maybe there is a better way than extending `Function.prototype`.

Comment: I'm trying to do the following:  
`Function.prototype.future = function() { var fn = this; var owner = ???; return fn.bind(owner, arguments); };`

Comment: There aren't "two `this` variables."  Your only choice is to pass it in as a parameter.

Comment: I don't think `fn.bind.apply(owner)` would work as you expect (if `owner` is not a function). And it still does not explain what your actual goal is. I can only assume so far that extending `Function.prototype` is not the right way.

Comment: In this case, my goal is to make it easy to create futures/promises out of a function and a set of arguments. The result can be used for lazy evaluation. But there are probably other applications as well.

Comment: I'm not so much familiar with that, but you might want to take a look at how jQuery implements their [`deferred` object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/).

Comment: I think you are trying to reinvent `bind(this)` without having to pass `this`. You will have to pass a context some how so you might as well use `bind(this)` after all.

Comment: @clockworkgeek. I think you're right. I realized the same thing after writing the code out in full. I guess such a capability would be useful in other situations, but here I should just use `bind(this)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to pass it in as a parameter to the function call... not sure if this is possible in your specific usage.

```
myMethod(this);

function myMethod( parent ) {
    // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

SpiderMonkey and JScript implements a non-standard "caller" property on Function-objects. I don't know the extent of the support in other browsers.

I belive it should be accessible like this:

```
Function.prototype.myMethod = function() {
   var fn = this;
   var owner = this.caller;
   /** ... */
};
```

but haven't tested it. As I said, it's not part of ECMA standard.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Caller